# C++ Test macro defined value of type information

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a macro like this:

```
#define MYDEFINE classX
```

And it could be

```
#define MYDEFINE classY
```

in some other places

where classX and classY is some typename.

What is the best way to check if the `MYDEFINE` is `classX` or `classY` ? (It could be more than 2 types here, so I'm seeking some flexible solutions)

Edit: More on the usecase, I have a `config.h` file for the user to define what type to use. I have some compile time decision to make depending on this config value, but it's undesirable to change the way `config.h` works.

I'm open to solution available in C++/C++11

Comment: Why are these macros necessary? Maybe we need a better explanation on their use case. Couldn't you just print out member variables for a quick sanity check?

Comment: What is it C or C++? Answers might be different, provided you give us a better description of what you are really after.

Comment: Updated more information

Answer (score 3):

The conventional way is to use a separate macro to select between the definitions

```
#ifdef USE_X
#define MYDEFINE classX
#else
#define MYDEFINE classY
#endif
```

and use that when you need to know

```
#ifdef USE_X
// ...
#endif
```

Comment: I would prefer something that will not need additional variable / defined. One reason is, I may have not just classX/classY but could be more in the future to decide.

Answer (score 0):

What is your intention? If you need to execute some code, you can use function overloading:

```
void f(classX *)
{
    // Some actions for classX
}
void f(classY *)
{
    // Some actions for classY
}

f((MYDEFINE *) 0);
```

Or if you need to define something:

```
template<class > class traits; // not defined

template<>
class traits<classX>
{
    typedef <type-for-classX> type;
};

template<>
class traits<classY>
{
    typedef <type-for-classY> type;
};

traits<MYDEFINE>::type var;
```